# How to configure the GAE Datastore emulator on Windows?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Following the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) I have started the GAE Datastore Emulator from a CMD shell.

I used:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore start --data-dir=j:\projects\project\datastore
```

The output is:

```
WARNING: Reusing existing data in [j:\projects\project\datastore].
Executing: cmd /c C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\cloud-datastore-emulator\cloud_datastore_emulator.cmd start --host=localhost --port=8081 --store_on_disk=True --consistency=0.9 --allow_remote_shutdown j:\projects\project\datastore
[datastore] Jun 08, 2019 5:24:52 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.CloudDatastore$FakeDatastoreAction$9 apply
[datastore] INFO: Provided --allow_remote_shutdown to start command which is no longer necessary.
[datastore] Jun 08, 2019 5:24:52 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.LocalDatastoreFileStub <init>
[datastore] INFO: Local Datastore initialized:
[datastore]     Type: High Replication
[datastore]     Storage: j:\projects\jupiter\datastore\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin
[datastore] Jun 08, 2019 5:24:53 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.LocalDatastoreFileStub load
[datastore] INFO: The backing store, j:\projects\project\datastore\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin, does not exist. It will be created.
[datastore] API endpoint: http://localhost:8081
[datastore] If you are using a library that supports the DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:
[datastore]
[datastore]   export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081
[datastore]
[datastore] Dev App Server is now running.
[datastore]
[datastore] The previous line was printed for backwards compatibility only.
[datastore] If your tests rely on it to confirm emulator startup,
[datastore] please migrate to the emulator health check endpoint (/). Thank you!
```

Browsing to `localhost:8081` returns `Ok`

In a second CMD shell I try:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init --data-dir=j:\projects\project\datastore > set_vars.cmd && set_vars.cmd
```

(Google docs don't mention `--data-dir=j:\projects\project\datastore` but without it the tool looks in the wrong place)

But it fails with:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.emulators.datastore.env-init) Unable to find env.yaml in the data_dir 
[C:\Users\c\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\emulators\datastore]. Please ensure you have started the appropriate emulator.
```

If I set-up the environment variables manually I get the same results from my CMD shells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried to reproduced your use case scenario and it worked for me. This is what I have followed:

1. From [Running the Datastore mode Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) documentation.
2. Make sure that **A Java JRE (version 8 or greater)** is installed.
3. Install the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) (If already have, update it)
4. Run the CMD as administrator
5. Execute `$ gcloud components install cloud-datastore-emulator`
6. Exectue `$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start --data-dir=C:\PATH\TO\datastore`
7. If get `You do not currently have this command group installed. Using it requires the installation of components: [beta]`
8. Then execute `$ gcloud components install beta`
9. Execute again `$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start --data-dir=C:\PATH\TO\datastore`
10. Open new CMD again as administrator
11. Execute `$ gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init --data-dir=C:\PATH\TO\datastore > set_vars.cmd && set_vars.cmd`
12. The command executed without any issues. This is the response:

```
C:\Windows\system32>set DATASTORE_DATASET=[PROJECT_ID]

C:\Windows\system32>set DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081

C:\Windows\system32>set DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST_PATH=localhost:8081/datastore

C:\Windows\system32>set DATASTORE_HOST=http://localhost:8081

C:\Windows\system32>set DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=[PROJECT_ID]

C:\Windows\system32>
```

I would suggest to try the process again from different directory. Make sure that:

- You have admin permissions to access the directory.
- For testing purposes, try a directory in your desktop.
- Update the Google Cloud SDK.
- The directory's path don't have a space in it.
- Both CMDs should open with administrative privileges.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to help. I now have the local datastore working. I think Google's code was getting confused by the presence of both Python 2 & 3 on my system. Once I sorted that then I just had to launch MS Visual Code *after* I had set_vars.cmd.

Comment: Hello, I am happy that you have found solution to your issue. If my answer was helpful please mark it as solution to give the question more visibility. Otherwise, if you have used a different solution, please post anther answer to this question and mark it as solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED 2019-09-07 following comments.

If you are stuck with Google App Engine (GAE) Standard Python 2.7, and have to run local version of GDS, here is my way of doing it (thought not an answer directly to the question, but still might be relevant to).
I run dev_appengine with datastore parameters. on windows the .bat file might look like this:

```
set PY="c:\/python27\/python.exe"
set GAE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py"
set GCSEMU="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\cloud-datastore-emulator\cloud_datastore_emulator.cmd"

%PY% %GAE% --skip_sdk_update_check=True --datastore_emulator_cmd=%GCSEMU% --port 8080 --host oe.loc .
```

There are parameters for store location too.

Comment: Google has deprecated dev_appserver.py and the App Engine api that came with it. The next api is a reboot and is more straightforward to apply. But

Comment: @Carl, maybe I was not following it closely. I understand that if you develop with GAE Standard python 3, you just run flask and no need in a dev_appserver. That is where standalone GDS emulator comes handly. The future version of our backend will be Py3. So my answer, which probably should not have been an answer but a comment to the accepted answer above, is just for people who are, like me, stuck maintaining GAE Py2. AFAIK we still have to use dev_appserver. Do you know of any other way running GAE Py2 server locally?

Comment: ‘fraid I don’t. I’ve ported from py2 to py3 and Google’s app engine refresh. I moved from web2py to flask. I’m using Google Talent api which doesn’t have a local option. Multiple server instances is my alternative approach.